# Converting a "equality sign delimiter" text file to excel format through a script or other means

Tags: excel, text, delimiter

For example, my data in my text file is as follow: (in the below link)

[text snippet that needs formatting to excel row|column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld2nW.png)

I want to convert this file to an excel format, where the titles before the equality sign are headers, and then the information on the right are recorded right under the headers. But the thing is, I have been looking all over the internet for this , but the only solutions I came up with are for specific excel friendly text formats, where all the headers are in the first row separated by a delimiter, then followed by the information that goes under throughout the text. Could anyone guide my what I should look into or how can i approach this ?

Comment: Power Query can certainly handle this kind of problem.  Your example seems to show three identical properties though. So you will have to give some thought as to how you want to handle that -- aggregate or not.

Comment: Im sorry i just copy pasted the same data over and over to paint some sort of picture. In actuality,  it's going to be different sets of data for each property. Thank you for the suggestion, ill definitely look into it.